# Azure Logic App Get File Content greater than 300MB

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-logic-apps

I want to create an logic app which list all my files on my azure file storage and then copy them to an SFTP server. I have setup the following flow
1. List files in file storage
2. Get meta data of file
3. Get content of file
4. Create file on SFTP

With files smaller than 300MB everything works fine, but when I want to copy an file > 300MB I get 
"The file contains 540.782 megabytes which exceeds the maximum 300 megabytes."

So is there an workaround or another solution for my issue?

Comment: Could you get get the file now?

Answer (score 0):

This limit could caused it's still a preview feature, and then I test with blob it doesn't have this limit.

So I suppose you could call a function to upload the file yo blob after get the file name then use blob connector to get the blob content and upload to ftp server.

The below is my function code, In my test I don't pass the file name from request, so you could change it to get the name from request.

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestMessage req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");


            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("storage connection string");

            CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();

            CloudFileShare share = fileClient.GetShareReference("windows");


            CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();

            String filename = "Downloads.zip";

            CloudFile file = rootDir.GetFileReference(filename);
            string fileSas = file.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessFilePolicy()
            {
                // Only read permissions are required for the source file.
                Permissions = SharedAccessFilePermissions.Read,
                SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(24)
            });
            Uri fileSasUri = new Uri(file.StorageUri.PrimaryUri.ToString() + fileSas);
            var myClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            var container = myClient.GetContainerReference("test");
            var blockBlob= container.GetBlockBlobReference("test.zip");
            await blockBlob.StartCopyAsync(fileSasUri);

            return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"success");

        }
```

The below is my test flow. Note the blob path, you need to modify it with this `/test/@{body('Get_file_metadata')?['DisplayName']}`.

[image]

And this is the result pic, from the size you could I test with a file more than 300MB.

[image]